# Does VirtualBox 6.0 automatically share hosts VPN with guest OS

Tags: virtualbox, vpn, 19.04

I use PIA on host system, Ubuntu 19.04, and run Centos in VirtualBox 6.0. PIA suggests to go to their website, http://www.privateinternetaccess.com , to see if their VPN is working. It will show IP, and states whether you are protected on top of page. When I visit site with guest OS it shows same IP as host, and says protected, and shows ISP as PIA. I only question this because I've seen a ton of questions on how to share host VPN with guest OS when my VPN apparently was shared automatically.

Answer (score 2):

VirtualBox or any other VM uses NAT by default. This means it will use the masquerade behind the host network. If the host uses an VPN, so will the guest.